# Javascript: Executing 2 functions after each other onmouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a question regarding the jquery/javascript:
I'm in the following situation:

- I have a link
- It has a property onmouseover
- When I hover it calls a default FirstFunction(), this function replaces the image.

Note I'm not allowed to modify that FirstFunction(), as it executes some different important tasks.
What I want to do:

- Call a second function:
- The second function should replace the image back to original, so before it was changed by the before FirstFunction()

I wrote a following script:

```
function SecondFunction(obj) {
    a = $(obj).find("img");
    if (a != null && a.attr("src")!= null)
        if (a.attr("src").lastIndexOf("img_4") != -1)
            a.attr("src", "newSmallImg.png");
        else if(a.attr("src").lastIndexOf("img_2")!=-1){
            a.attr("src", "newBigImg.png");
        }
}
```

Normally when I debug the script, it works etc etc, but the image is not replaced back. And i've noticed that "SecondFunction" is finished before the "FirstFunctions" is finished executing.

Can I do something about it? Like setting in SecondFunction => FirstFunction.ready? (The first function is also in a different file.)

Any input would be welcome

Small update, I'm calling the functions as follows:

```
<a onmouseover="FirstFunction(); SecondFunction(this);" ...>
    <span>
       <img src="" ... />
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: did you tried this `onmouseover="firstFunction();secondFunction();"` ??

Comment: How are you executing the functions and in what order? Are you executing SecondFunction as a callback?

Comment: Is `firstFunction()` performing any asynchronous operations, such as making AJAX requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) check the object type you're receiving in your second function, how are you calling this function? can you provide the code?

2) check that the image your are finding in this line, is the one you expect:

```
a = $(obj).find("img");
```

I recommed to access the objects [by an  unique id](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

```
var myImge = $('#imageId')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do something about it? Like setting in SecondFunction =>
>   FirstFunction.ready? (The first function is also in a different file.)

Possible this helps you

```
<a onmouseover="FirstFunction(this, SecondFunction)" ...>
    <span>
       <img src="" ... />
    </span>
</a>
```

And change `FirstFunction()` like this

```
function FirstFunction(obj, callback) {
    //your code here

    if(callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(obj);
    }
}
```